# Writing to CON (Windows console) doesn't print to STDOUT (console)

Tags: go, console, stdout, tty

I understood that the `CON` name is equivalent to `/dev/tty` in Linux.
But when I used a program that write to this file, it doesn't print anything, it works only on Linux.
I think I am not using it correctly.
**IMPORTANT:** I am not looking for workarounds like `fmt.Println`, I need to be able to print to this file, like I did in Linux (`/dev/tty`).

This is the program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
)


func main() {

    var ttyName string
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        fmt.Println("*** Using `con`")
        ttyName = "con"
    } else {
        fmt.Println("*** Using `/dev/tty`")
        ttyName = "/dev/tty"
    }

    f, _ := os.OpenFile(ttyName, os.O_WRONLY, 0644)

    fmt.Fprintln(f, "*** Stdout redirected")
}
```

The program prints  `"*** Stdout redirected"` in Linux but not in Windows.
The problem is related to the `ttyName`.
I used `con` as the name but it seems that it doesn't work.
I also tried:  `"con:"`, `"\\\\.\\con"`, `"\\\\.\\con:"`, `"\\\\?\\con"`, and `conout`.

How can I use it to print to the console?

I took some of the ideas from this website:
https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/dev_console.5.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you test this with Windows Command Prompt as `CON` might not work as expected with 3rd party terminal emulators (like embedded ones in IDE, Hyper.js, etc.).

Options you listed should work, `CON` (legacy DOS name) or `\\.\CON` (UNC name) in uppercase are safe bet:

```golang
f, _ := os.OpenFile("CON", os.O_WRONLY, 0644) 
f, _ := os.OpenFile("\\\\.\\CON", os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
```

Comment: Have you tried in Command Prompt? Writing to CON is known to misbehave in various 3rd party terminal emulators.

Comment: Yes, you right, it works (`"CON"`) on the console. Interesting why it doesn't work on Goland IDE console.

Comment: @E235 I think those 3rd party terminals do weird stuff to make windows console behave like pseudo tty because by default Windows component ConHost that provides console API behaves differently (doesn't support same escapes, etc.)

Comment: @balmi Weird, because on Linux it also works with the Goland IDE.

Comment: @E235 That's all right, on Linux console Goland attaches to is raw pseudo-tty. On Windows there's glue between Goland console and Windows console that makes Windows console look like a pseudo-tty (and where I believe the message is lost).

Comment: @E235 there's great series posted on all those differences [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-backgrounder/) if you are interested.